# Integrate calendar into Oracle forms app

Tags: oracle, forms, date, calendar

Hi guys :)    i want to integrate a ready made CALENDAR on my oracle forms application whether it's a java applet or other available option ; i want the end user to be able to invoke this CALENDAR whenever he pressed a button so that he can choose a specific date to be entered in a display item .

Comment: I don't believe this should be a community wiki

Comment: what do you mean by (( Comunity wiki )) ??

Comment: @Mousarules: When you asked the question, it appears that you checked the "community wiki" check box. Questions are usually marked "community wiki" if the question has no well-defined answer. In your case, there is probably a well-defined answer. As well, when people answer a question marked "community wiki", they don't earn any reputation from their answers' up-votes.

Comment: thanks adam , i got it all , i didn't mea it that way but still there are no well-defined answers to my question .
tanks again .

Comment: @Mousarules: Perhaps I wasn't entirely clear. I was referring to questions that *cannot possibly* have well-defined answers. For example: "What's the best programming language?". *That* question cannot possibly have a well-defined answer. *Your* question however, *can* have a well-defined answer, just nobody has come up with one yet. :)

Comment: Ohhh...i see :)  i'm glad you are in my side lol , i really hope that there is a well-defined answer to my question ...and most important ; someone would lead me to it :S  .
Many thanks Adam , appreciate your concern :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention which version of Oracle forms you are using?

Have you looked at the demo's on the Oracle Forms OTN [page](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/products/forms/index.html)? There is a calendar PJC included in the [Oracle Forms 10gR2 Demos](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/demos/Forms_Demos_10gr2.zip).

**Edit:**

My reasoning for including the link to the forms demos is that you can look at the calendar demo, then perhaps you can use a similar method to invoke your one

Comment: Thanks for your concern :)
forms version 9.0.4.0.19